# Error in Integration Services Catalog about the REST API

Tags: ssis, ssms, jira, kingswaysoft

I worked on extracting data from Jira, using the kingswaysoft Rest Api. It workes fine while on Visual Studio but, once i deploy it to Management Studio, i get an error stating:

> Data Flow Task:Error: An error occurred with the following error
> message:
> "KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.ProductivityPack.Rest.RestServiceException:
> Basic authentication with passwords is deprecated.  For more
> information, see:
> https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-with-passwords-for-jira-and-confluence-apis-972355348.html
> (SSIS Productivity Pack, v21.1.0.1551 - ISServerExec,
> v13.0.5026.0)KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.ProductivityPack.Http.HttpServiceException
> : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. (Error Type
> / Reason: Unauthorized, Detailed Message: Basic authentication with
> passwords is deprecated.  For more information, see:
> https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-with-passwords-for-jira-and-confluence-apis-972355348.html
> )System.Net.WebException  (Status Reason: Unauthorized): The remote
> server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.".

I have tried changing the connection string multiple times (Adding the API key, encoding it to Base64), but so far with no success. Example of one of my tries:

> ServiceName=Jira;PathToTokenFile=;AuthenticationMode=Basic;ConsumerKey=;ServerUrl=linkurl;ApiThrottleRate=0;CertificatePath=;Username=username:apitoken;ProxyMode=Manual;ProxyUsername=proxyusername;ProxyServer=proxyserver;ProxyServerPort=proxyport;ServiceTimeout=120;RetryOnIntermittentErrors=True;IgnoreCertificateErrors=False

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is thrown due to the Basic authentication [deprecation in Jira](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/), and we support API Token and OAuth in the connection manager, which is what we would recommend using since you are running into such errors. For more details on OAuth authentication, please refer to the below documentation. However, if you need assistance in configuring these, please contact our support team.

- List item

[Configuring OAuth Consumers - JIRA 4.2 - Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA042/Configuring+OAuth+Consumers)